# Missing Assimp lib after install it via CMake

Tags: dll, cmake, assimp

Is there a proper way to install and link assimp via CMake.

**Graphics.cmake**

```
...
message(STATUS "Building the ASSIMP")
set(ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS OFF)
set(ASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
set(ASSIMP_INSTALL OFF)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/application/dependencies/ASSIMP)
install(
    TARGETS assimp
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin 
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib 
)
message(STATUS "ASSIMP - Done!\n")
...
```

**CMakeLists.txt** looks like:

```
...
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
...
include(Graphics)
set(DEP_EMSDK_LIBS
    soil2
    assimp
)
...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MAIN} 
                    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES}
                    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDES}
                    ${CFG_FILES}
                )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DEP_LIBS}) 
target_include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/application/includes>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/application/includes>
) 
...
```

I've erased a bunch of redundant staff. Also I've been trying to do a lot of options `install(...)` however as the result I'm always missing the `assimp-vc142-mt.dll` in the `bin`.
If it is essential, the compiler is msvc, and generator Visual Studio 2019. Where did I admit a mistake?

Comment: "however as the result I'm always missing the assimp-vc140-mt.dll in the lib." - `.dll` is RUNTIME part of the library, this is explicitely written in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/install.html#installing-targets). According to your `install()` invocation, RUNTIME part is placed in the `bin`, not in the `lib`.

Comment: Oops, in /bin of course, I’ll fix it, thanks. Though, I was checking everywhere

Comment: Are you sure that you build assimp as a **shared** library, but not as a **static**? Note, that `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)` doesn't affect on assimp, because it sets "normal" CMake variable, but Assimp's `CMakeLists.txt` [defines](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L59) CACHED variable for that purpose. (In other words, if you build your project with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`, then Assimp builds the static library).

Comment: BTW, **installing** into binary directory (`${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin`) looks weird. Also, this installation could conflict with `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` setting you have.